# adding attributes to a Ruby object dynamically

Tags: ruby

I have an object created, and I want, based on some conditional check, to add some attributes to this object. How can I do this? 
To explain what I want:

```
A=Object.new
if(something happens)
{
  #make A have another attibute say age
  #& store something in A.age

}
```

Answer (score 51):

First of all the thing about ruby is that it allows a different syntax which is used widely by ruby coders. Capitalized identifiers are Classes or Constants (thanks to [sepp2k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/149392/sepp2k) for his comment), but you try to make it an object. And almost nobody uses `{}` to mark a multiline block.

```
a = Object.new
if (something happens)
  # do something
end
```

I'm not sure what your question is, but I have an idea, and this would be the solution:

If you know what attributes that class can have, and it's limited you should use

```
class YourClass
  attr_accessor :age
end
```

`attr_accessor :age` is short for:

```
def age
  @age
end
def age=(new_age)
  @age = new_age
end
```

Now you can do something like this:

```
a = YourClass.new
if (some condition)
  a.age = new_value
end
```

If you want to do it completely dynamically you can do something like this:

```
a = Object.new
if (some condition)
  a.class.module_eval { attr_accessor :age}
  a.age = new_age_value
end
```

Comment: using capitals for class is not ruby "syntax" but common convention. I told you already - I am not yet too much a ruby guy.
Btw your solution works good enough for me. Thanks.

Comment: I know that this is common convention, that's why I wrote "Capitalized identifiers **should** be Classes" and I saw that you're new to ruby, so I thought, I show you how most ruby coders would do it. And the syntax thing was about the paranthesis for the if block

Comment: @Nikhil: Actually it *is* syntax, not a matter of convention. Any identifier that start with a capital letter is a constant in ruby. So `a = Object.new` and `A = Object.new` do too very different things (the first defines a local variable, the other a global constant).

Comment: AAh...
That would be useful to me! Wonder how I never came across it. 
Thanks anyway :)

Comment: but this would make all instances of the class have this attribute, not just the object

Comment: I don't understand why this complicated solution gets more votes than my simple solution.  Maybe just because it's more versatile; it can be applied to any object even if it isn't an OpenStruct.

Comment: The original question, as stated (rather than guessing at what we think the poster meant) doesn't ask how to add attributes to every instance of a class but rather to a specific instance of a class.  This implies adding the attribute to only the instance and not to every instance of the class. Jonas and user102008 provided answers that are correct.

Comment: LOL such a ruby answer.  Instead of answering the question, a dissertation on why the OPs question was not posed in the ruby way.

Answer (score 26):

You could use an OpenStruct:

```
a = OpenStruct.new
if condition
    a.age = 4
end
```

Or just use a plain old hash.

Answer (score 21):

This adds the attribute to only the object:

```
a = Object.new
if (something happens)
  class << a
    attr_accessor :age
  end
  a.age = new_age_value
end
```

Answer (score 13):

If the name of the attribute is known at code-writing time then you can do what was suggested already:

```
class A
end

a = A.new
a.age = 20 # Raises undefined method `age='

# Inject attribute accessors into instance of A
class << a
  attr_accessor :age
end

a.age = 20 # Succeeds
a.age # Returns 20

b = A.new
b.age # Raises undefined method, as expected, since we only modified one instance of A
```

However, if the attribute's name is dynamic and only known at runtime then you'll have to call `attr_accessor` a bit differently:

```
attr_name = 'foo'

class A
end

a = A.new
a.foo = 20 # Raises undefined method `foo='

# Inject attribute accessors into instance of A
a.instance_eval { class << self; self end }.send(:attr_accessor, attr_name)

a.foo = 20 # Succeeds
a.foo # Returns 20
```

Comment: You can also do `a.singleton_class.send(:attr_accessor, attr_name)`.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You can use `instance_variable_set` to set a variable on an instance of the Object class (and `instance_variable_get` to get it.) The Object class doesn't have any attributes you can set directly.

However, I suspect this is not the best solution for what you are trying to achieve; it is not the norm to directly work with the Object class, but rather to define or use classes that inherit from it, that have the attributes you want to work with.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Person; end
person = Person.new
person.age # throws NoMethodError

if true
  person.singleton_class.module_eval { attr_accessor :age }
end

person.age = 123
person.age #=> 123

person2 = Person.new
person2.age #=> throws NoMethodError
```